# How to get ID from LOV?

Tags: oracle-apex

**I'm learning APEX 5**

I have a control named `X_CONTROL`, where I want to populate his content with an SQL query.

To do that, I need the ID primary key from a table, which should be the `ID` of the row selected on a Select List control named `MY_LIST_CONTROL`.

`MY_LIST_CONTROL` has a list of values taken from a column of the table `"MyTable"`, which is not the ID primary key.

I tried to populate `X_CONTROL` with this SQL

```
Select ID from MyTable where ColumnName=:MY_LIST_CONTROL
```

It doesn't work, and should not work because ColumnName is not "unique", like `ID` is.

**So, the question is, how do I recover, with SQL, the ID of the selected row which correspond to the selected value in MY_LIST_CONTROL.**

It should be SQL, because APEX 5 demands an SQL query to populate the `X_CONTROL`.

Comment: Your question is not currently very clear.  You contradict yourself when you say "how do I recover, with SQL, the ID of the selected row which correspond to the selected value in MY_LIST_CONTROL" - but you just said there will be more than one matching row for a given MY_LIST_CONTROL value - which is it?

Comment: @Tony Andrews MY_LIST_CONTROL takes his list of values from a column which is not marked as "unique", so it can, potentially have duplicated data. Only columns flagged as "unique", or "primary key" have unique values. I have a table named MyTable with columns named ID and ListOfValues. MY_LIST_CONTROL has one of ListOfValues selected, and I need to know what is the ID of the selected value, to populate another control.

Comment: @Tony Andrews Do you mean that the LOV should only have unique values? I'm learning, so I'm not sure about that.

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set up a simple example [here on apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=82795:32):
[image]

Whenever a Department is selected (item P32_DEPTNO), its Location is copied into the second item (P32_LOC).

This is done by a dynamic action on P32_DEPTNO defined as follows:

- Event: Change
- Selection Type: Item(s)
- Item(s): P32_DEPTNO

TRUE Action:

- Action: Set Value
- Set Type: SQL Statement
- SQL Statement:
  select loc 
    from dept
   where deptno = :P32_DEPTNO
- Items to Submit: P32_DEPTNO

Comment: I already have that LOV. That is the LOV of MY_LIST_CONTROL. My problem is that I need to recover the ID=10 (in your example "deptno" column=10 when :MY_LIST_CONTROL = 'ACCOUNTING'), to populate another control named X_CONTROL, using SQL on X_CONTROL.

Comment: So, in X_CONTROL I need this SQL: **Select deptno from dept where dname =:MY_LIST_CONTROL** but it doesn't works

Comment: Actually, I need the ID=10 to access other columns to fill X_CONTROL, but that's unnecessary detail. If I can get the 10, I should be able to figure how to use it. This should be a common task, so I do not understand why is so hard to find it with google.

Comment: Sounds like you want a dynamic action that fires when the select list is changed and sets the value of X_CONTROL using a SQL query.

Comment: Yes, I had set the dynamic action to "refresh" X_CONTROL when MY_LIST_CONTROL  "changes", but I cannot fetch the data from the table, because the SQL code on X_CONTROL doesn't know the ID

Comment: That is why I tried **Select ID from MyTable where ColumnName=:MY_LIST_CONTROL**

Comment: You just need to tell the dynamic action to post the value of the ID item, then the SQL will know,

Comment: I do not see any property in the Dynamic Action capable of transfering the data. What are the keywords which I need to google about how to transfer the ID from MY_LIST_CONTROL  to X_CONTROL? I have no clue, and I had been searching for days. I'm getting crazy, because this should be a very basic and common task, and yet I cannot find any explanation.

Comment: Is this the functionality you want? https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=82795:32

Comment: This is an APEX 5 screen capture of the properties of the Dynamic Action https://i.imgur.com/Lz3DPnG.png Do you mean that the ID should be passed on one of those properties as a parameter?

Comment: I'm learning the first steps, so I do not know what is the right terminology.

Comment: No, lower down in the TRUE action's properties - under Settings: "Items to submit".

Comment: "Is this the functionality you want" I do not see any Select List Control on the example you linked

Comment: Please try again - I had failed to enable deep linking so you got to wrong page :-(

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do (the second control is an image control for me, but that's not relevant)

Comment: "See updated answer": seems to be what I'm looking for (I expected "Set Value" to set a value in the child control, but it looks like it sets a value, and then submits it to the control. It's a bit confusing.

Comment: I still need to chew it, but you had been very helpful. Hope you like metal: here is a reward https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aj50wMJ83zc